# Visual studio 2012 not generating a .exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have been developing an application using GDI+ and C++, and for no reason that I can tell, Visual Studio has been throwing up the error

> Unable to start program 'I:\AI and Physics....filepath\PPAIE4GProR1.exe'.
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

And when I look, sure enough, no .exe. Any ideas as to why this would start to happen? It has been working perfectly fine up until now.

Comment: Right-click on the Solution in the SolutionExplorer window, then choose "CLEAN". Wait until it finishes. Then, go to Output window and rightclick there. Choose "CLEAR". Then, rebuild everything and look for any ERRORS in the OUTPUT window (not only in the "Errors" window). Also, in that OUTPUT window, find and check what PATHS are being used, that is, look at all log messages and check if the files are being written to correct folders - your EXE could have been simply written elsewhere. Finally, after all of this, report here with all the findings.

Comment: There are the same warnings to do with type conversions, and there is 1>  PPEGProR1.vcxproj -> I:\AI and Physics\PPAIE4GProC++_GDIR1\.\Debug\PPAIE4GProR1.exe at the end, which says to me it should be there

Comment: Oh, it was there, and then deleted itself as soon as I tried to access it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the linker report an error?  It may not have write access to the directory?  A slightly more far fetched possibility is that an over-zealous virus scanner is deleting it as soon as it's created.

Comment: No error, and when I build it it comes up as build succeeded, and The virus scanner doesn't seem likely as it was working seconds before

Comment: Well then, reboot?  *grin*

Comment: The fabled "Turn it off and on again" has failed for the first time in recorded history

Comment: I think it was the virus scanner, bizzarely. I set an exclusion filepath in desperation after clean rebuilding, and it now works